# Server-Side second HTTP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, server-side, httpresponse

Is there a way to, from server-side code in C#, send an HTTP Request and gather the result? What I want to do is this:

1. HTTPRequest sent from client browser to page
2. Server-Side C# code does some boolean checking
3. If checking pans out, send and HTTPRequest to another page
4. Get HTTPResponse and populate to innerHTML of a div
5. Send itself's HTTPResponse to the client browser for viewing

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do you have any problems doing that?

Comment: What have you tried?  [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+http+request) has some suggestions.

Comment: @carlosfigueira I'm unsure of the syntax involved in doing so. Could you post an example?

Comment: @zimdanen So I can use the HttpWebRequest then as I would from a console app. It won't have an adverse effects due to running under IIS or anything? (HttpWebRequest was used in a google search link I noticed on the list)

Comment: No, it works fine under IIS as well.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx

Comment: @carlosfigueira Terrific. Thank you. If you post a short answer about HttpWebRequest I'd be glad to accept.

Comment: You may prefer [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) over HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same libraries which you'd use on a "normal" (i.e., client) application on the server side as well. `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, etc., they should work just fine.

One note, though: if you make synchronous requests (`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse`, `WebClient.DownloadData`, etc.), those requests will block the server thread, so if you need to scale the server to serve a large number of clients this may become a problem. If that happens, you can consider making your operation asynchronous. But you shouldn't do it unless you have a (current or foreseeable) problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's possible.  You can look into HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx